# Can't ssh, permission denied

Tags: centos, ssh

I have created new user using `useradd USER`, but I can't SSH to the server and login with it. I already have another account to which I can SSH easily.

Running `ssh -v USER@domain.tld` is returning this message after entering password:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
```

When trying acocunt that works I get

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
```

I know the password is correct, because once I SSH using the working account I can change user successfully.

Comment: What do the server logs say when you're trying the failed login?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Turned out that `/etc/ssh/sshd.conf` had `AllowUsers` line. Resolved it by adding new user to that line and restarting SSH.

Comment: Great :) it was located here /etc/ssh/sshd_config and I just restarted sshd after changes and it worked.

Comment: for me it was AllowedGroups but same cause/fix

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem that permissions of .ssh and authorized_keys were not right.  Setting 700 to .ssh and 600 to authorized_keys solved the issue.